# Inserting dynamic amount of rows based off Amount of IDS found from search

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert into the table TAKES(ID, COURSEID, SEC_ID, SEMESTER, YEAR , GRADE) off all the students who have not taken a certain course.
I correctly get the IDS needed from the table with the call

```sql
select ID from student
where dept_name = 'Computer Science'
minus
select ID from takes
where course_id = 'CS-347';
```

then I go to actually insert it with these IDS that I have retrieved and all the other fields for insert are static.

```sql
insert into TAKES
SELECT ID,'CS-347' as COURSE_ID,1 as SEC_ID,'Spring' as SEMESTER,2021 as YEAR,NULL as GRADE
from student
where dept_name = 'Computer Science'
minus
select ID from takes
where course_id = 'CS-347';
```

I then get the an error:

> Incorrect number of result columns.

I know that I am only pulling from the Student column, but I'm not sure how to work around this as in I have tried selecting the IDS individually and that didn't work either.

Comment: Mysql does not support the minus operator, so this code cannot possibly for mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this query instead :

```
insert into  TAKES (column names)
SELECT
    ID,
    'CS-347' as COURSE_ID,
    1 as SEC_ID,
    'Spring' as SEMESTER,
    2021 as YEAR,
    NULL as GRADE
from
    student
where
    dept_name = 'Computer Science' 
and ID NOT IN  (select
    ID
from
    takes
where
    course_id = 'CS-347');
```

when you use minus both side of operation need of return them same number of columns . also make sure you are inserting the right columns , better to mention column names

Comment: `NOT IN` is generally best avoided because of problems with nullable columns, best use `NOT EXISTS` or `EXCEPT`

Comment: @ConnorMills . . . This answer emphasizes that while set operations are theoretically appealing, in practice, they tend to solve one problem and are not very flexible.